# Is it possible to change the column width using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have xlsx format spreadsheets. For each one I need to set the column width for all but one column to 25 and the width of the remaining column to 50. The unit of measurement is the  [idiosyncratic one Excel uses](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214123/description-of-how-column-widths-are-determined-in-excel).

The spreadsheets are originally produced in Google sheets which has no way to do this so currently I have to download them in xlsx format and then email them to a friend who has Excel to have them fixed as I don't own a copy of Excel myself. This is clearly far from ideal.

> Is it possible to set the column widths using openpyxl?

Comment: Always helps if you look at the documentation.

Comment: @CharlieClark True. I find the different units very confusing.

Comment: They are confusing because they are OS and device specific but they are covered by the OOXML specification and not the repsonsibility of openpyxl.

Comment: @CharlieClark In openpyxl how do you specify if the width is in points, pixels, or the default Excel units?

Comment: The units are related to the width of the widest character in the typeface being used. For further information please refer to the OOXML specification.

Comment: @CharlieClark Those are the default Excel units. But it should also be possible to specify the width in  terms of pixels or points I think.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Openpyxl column width](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension.width)

```
ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 25
```