# How openpyxl can change "all" the sizes of cells?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906532/is-it-possible-to-change-the-column-width-using-openpyxl) link shows how to do for one column but how can I efficiently do it for all the columns?

I found [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html) documentation page but couldn't figure out the usage of it

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looping over the columns? And why wasn't that efficient enough?

Comment: I am not sure how big the sheet will get also after A-Z column ids become AA AB AC--ZX ZY ZZ. Not sure how to handle them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at openpyxl I understand your concerns about efficiency. There's a lot of looping.
But this seems to work:

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('openpyxl/tests/data/genuine/libreoffice_nrt.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
column_letters = (col[0].column_letter for col in sheet)
for letter in column_letters:
    sheet.column_dimensions[letter].width = 25
```